# How do you calculate the kernel of a bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the bilinear form $\beta_A(v,w)=v^TAw$

with

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
     2 & 3 & 5 \\
     3 & 1 & 4 \\
     5 & 4 & 9 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

Calculate all the linear subspaces $U \subset \mathbb{R^3}$, such that $\beta_A(v,u)=0$ $\forall v\in \mathbb{R^3}, u\in U$

Since the matrix is symmetric, this kernel is the kernel of $\beta_A$.

My attempt:

$$ker(\beta_A)=\{u\in \mathbb{R^3} |\forall v \in \mathbb{R^3}: \beta_A(v,u)=0 \} \\=\{u\in \mathbb{R^3} |\forall v \in \mathbb{R^3}: v_1\beta_A(e_1,u)+v_2\beta_A(e_2,u)+v_3\beta_A(e_3,u)=0 \} $$

When I in $\beta_A$, with $u=(x,y,z)^T$ I get

$$x(2v_1+3v_2+5v_3)+y(3v_1+v_2+4v_3)+z(5v_1+4v_2+9v_3)=0$$

Which is 6 variables in one equation. How do I tackle this? Is this even the correct approach?

Comment: What is the kernel of $A$ as a matrix?

Comment: Is this the solution?

Comment: in order for $vAu = 0$ for all $u$ then $vA = 0$ and $v$ is in the kernel of $A$

Comment: Is this standard notation? Wouldn't it be $Au=0$ for all $v$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They want to know a nonzero vector $u$ such that, no matter what $v$ is chosen, we are always going to get $u^T A v = 0.$ So, a fixed $u,$ then we get to chose $v,$ in a malicious way if desired.

I choose $v = Au.$

What does it tell me if
$$ u^T A A u = 0,  $$ knowing that $A^T = A;$
$$ u^T A^T A u = 0, $$
$$ (Au)^T (Au) = 0 $$

Essay question: given a column vector $w,$ what are other names for
$$ w^T w ?$$
In particular, what does it say about $w$ if $w^T w = 0?$

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "the logic symbols are not helping me". Also, why can you specify $u$, if the statement needs to hold for ALL $u$?

Comment: The expression you ask about is the dot product, and if its zero then $w$ is the zero vector. But I do not think that your answer is right, as the kernel of $A$ is nontrivial, and any vector $u$ from $ker(A)$ surely satisfies $v^T A u=0$ for any $v$.

Comment: @B.Swan slightly edited. Nothing needs to hold for all $u.$ It is unfortunate that they worded it that way

Comment: The part about $U$ is just that, if you find a $u$ that does this, then $2u$ does the same thing.  I hope you can get something out of this; the sort of distinction I am making does not come over well on computer screen, if you can get tutoring in person that will be better.

Comment: I think I understand the approach now, thank you. It still does lead to U=ker(A)$, though.